unable to get persian text output in visual studio code
When I want to print a persian text in visual studio code, it displays it with question marks in the terminal. Can someone help me to fix that please.
public class Ex1 {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    float size;
    float new_size;
    public void Converter(){
        System.out.println("مقدار پارچه را به مترمربع وارد کنید :");
        size = input.nextInt();
        new_size = size * 1.196f;
    }
    public void Print(){
        System.out.println(new_size);
    }
}
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ex1 first = new Ex1();
        first.Converter();
        first.Print();
        
    }
}

output: ????? ????? ?? ?? ??????? ???? ???? :

I'm going to take a wild guess that you're running VSC under Windows?

Yes, you're right. @g00se

It might be a good idea to try to run it under Powershell first. What happens?

Hi, you can change the encoding method with setting.json file. like this :
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
"JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS": "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
}

@Jeanneli worth a try if indeed that is the encoding. But it might be a problem with the output font

@g00se Actually I don't know how to run it under Powershell; I'm sorry I'm a beginner. But I tried to run it on the intelliJ idea and it hadn't any problem. I think there is something wrong with the VSC itself. I also tried to set the encoding on UTF-8 but it didn't change anything.

You would use the commands in the answer below to run it in Powershell

If you are using vs code you can check whether it is set to UTF-8 or you can try running on cmd so when you do javac follow the mentioned command
cmd: javac -encoding UTF-8 your_file_name.java
and then java your_file_name
try it and let me know.

I tried this but it didn't work unfortunately. It keeps displaying question mark or 'â?ƒ' on cmd. It only worked on intelliJ idea without any problem.

If you want to change the font, you can choose to use the shortcut key Ctrl+, to enter the settings. Input terminal.integrated to select the option to set the font. And to see if the encoding is UTF-8. Or refer to the  document for the content.  Can you get the results you want with this setting?
